# Is this the correct exercise solution?

Tags: java, exception

There is a exercise from Thinking in Java:

> Create a class called **FailingConstructor** with a constructor that might
>   fail partway through the construction process and throw an exception.
>   In **main()**,  write code that properly guards against this failure.

This is my solution:

```
class E1 extends Exception {
    private FailingConstructor f;
    E1(FailingConstructor f) { this.f = f; }
    FailingConstructor getF() { return f; }
}

class FailingConstructor {
    private Integer value;
    FailingConstructor(int i) throws E1 {
        if (i < 0) throw new E1(this);
        value = i;
    }
    void set(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public String toString() { return value.toString(); }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FailingConstructor f2 = new FailingConstructor(-11);
        } catch (E1 e) {
            e.getF().set(0);
            System.out.println(e.getF());
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me, is this the correct exercise solution? Solution I found ([here](http://greggordon.org/java/tij4/exceptions/FailingConstructor22.java)) looks rather strange and illogicaly and I think my solution is better than this.

Comment: both seem good. In your solution, a custom exception will be thrown when the validation you've implemented fails, in the other example, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown because they try to store a third element in an array with two elements.

Comment: I'm not sure that `e.getF().set(0);` is a correct way to handle that exception though. If there were other initialization statements in the constructor which would never have been called because of the exception the object might be in an undefined/unexpected state. Additionally `f2` would still be null since the assignment didn't happen. I'd rather create a new instance with a correct value instead of reusing the failed one.

Comment: Leaking the reference to the partly-constructed instance via the `new E1(this)` is a *terrible* idea. After all, it lets you call `e.getF().set(-1)`, and use the instance afterwards - which is exactly what the exception is being thrown to guard against.

Comment: And please note: in a certain sense, this is working code; so maybe codereview.stackexchange.com would have been a better place for this request. We help with problems here, we don't do code review. On the other hand, Eran pointed out quite some problems with your code; so I guess ... fair enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing a reference of the half constructed instance to the constructor of the exception seems like a bad idea to me.

And mutating that instance in the catch clause serves no purpose, since after the catch clause is executed, your code will have no reference to that instance anyway.

The catch clause should either report that an exception occurred (print an error message or stack trace), throw a different exception if applicable or - if `properly guards against this failure` means that the successful creation of an instance must be ensured - create a new instance of `FailingConstructor` whose creation is guaranteed not to throw an exception. If you choose the last approach, you should declare the `FailingConstructor` variable before the `try` block, in order for it to remain in scope after the try-catch block.

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FailingConstructor f2 = null;
        try {
            f2 = new FailingConstructor(-11);
        } catch (E1 e) {
            f2 = new FailingConstructor(); // one way to recover from the exception 
                                           // is to use a different constructor
                                           // that doesn't throw an exception
        }
        // now you can access f2
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that to declare variable before the try block is good idea? Constructor can throw the unchecked exception

Comment: @luckystrrrike If the constructor throws the exception and the variable is not initialized, it will remain null (assuming you set it to null when you declare it). You must declare it before the try block if you want to access it outside the try block.

Comment: but IDE doesn't allow to do this - it says 'Unhandled exception'
P.S. in the first comment I meant 'unhandled'

Comment: @luckystrrrike What do you mean? Where do you get `Unhandled exception`? Did you remove catch clause?

Comment: tbh, I'm confusing a little. I should put the string where I create the instance before try-catch block in order to ensure an access to it in the catch clauses. In the catch clauses I should assign new value to this variable via new, but what should I put in the try clauses?

Comment: @luckystrrrike see the example I added

Answer (score 2):

Leaking the reference to the partly-constructed instance via the `throw new E1(this)` is ill-advised.

It lets you call `e.getF().set(-1)`, and use the instance afterwards - which is exactly what the exception is being thrown to guard against.

There is no problem with throwing an exception - the problem is the reference to `FailingConstructor` that it is constructed with. Remove this (and the `getF()` method etc), and it is fine.

Comment: This is an example for study, you can set any value after creating, but the essential condition is to not allow to make a instance with a negative value

Comment: Right - but my point is that you *can* make an instance with a negative value, by calling `e.getF().set(-1)`.